# Showing Loading Gif while Bootstrap Carousel is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a loading gif that appears on the screen until all the Bootstrap carousel slides are loaded. It got it working when the images were from lorempixel.com. But, now I have two images that I wish to load.

The functionality works well on the first try. But, when I reload the page, the loading gif stays on the screen and will not disappear revealing the slides.

My Bootstrap Slider Code:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item">
<img class="large" src="http://localhost/agency/img/slide1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img class="large" src="http://localhost/agency/img/slide1.jpg" />
</div>
</div>  
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#homeCarousel" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#homeCarousel" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="loading">
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/loading.gif">
</div>
```

Script in the Head Section:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#content').hide();
$('#loading').show();
$('.large').bind('load', function() {
$('#loading').hide();
$('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#content').hide();
$('#loading').show();
$('.large').bind('load', function() {
$('#loading').hide();
$('#content').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

This code should go at bottom of the file, before `</body>` tag.

**Why it won't work while place in head?**
Because HTML usually get loaded from top to bottom, that means your script loaded before #content, #loading, etc elements loaded. For that reason your script wasn't able to find those element and did nothing.

*Note: I am not sure your script is proper or not, here I have answered about **"what you are doing wrong"**.*